# Neatbeans does not run Android Project

Tags: android, netbeans

I'm new to creating Android apps. I've always used Netbeans, so I downloaded a plugin for it, as well as the Android SDK. I set up an AVD and everything seems fine, at first.

When I compile and run my project, I get no errors, the AVD runs and the virtual environment is there, but my project is not. I cannot get my project to run in the AVD.

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1.
My Android SDK is 2.3.3, API 10.

Any help would be much appreciated. Does this perhaps have anything to do with changing my PATH variables? Thanks.

Following are what I get in the Console;

```
Gathering info for MyAndroidApp...
Android SDK Tools Revision 16
Project Target: Android 2.3.3
API level: 10
------------------
Resolving library dependencies:
No library dependencies.

------------------

WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
Creating output directories if needed...
----------
Handling aidl files...
No AIDL files to compile.
----------
Handling RenderScript files...
No RenderScript files to compile.
----------
Handling Resources...
Found Deleted Target File
Generating resource IDs...
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\bin\classes
Found Deleted Target File
Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\bin\classes.dex...
Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\res
To destination dir: C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\bin\res
Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache
Found Deleted Target File
Creating full resource package...
Found Deleted Target File
Creating MyAndroidApp-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
Running zip align on final apk...
Debug Package: C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\bin\MyAndroidApp-debug.apk
debug:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\bin\build.prop
Updating property file: C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\bin\build.prop
Updating property file: C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\bin\build.prop
Updating property file: C:\Users\Harry\Documents\IndianaJonesy\MyAndroidApp\bin\build.prop
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: are you get any message in log file or in console?

Comment: I estimate my projects with the **Eclipse IDE** in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have to do the installation of the application manually if you are using Netbeans IDE

Read it [here](http://www.techjail.net/how-to-run-android-apk-file-on-your-pc.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.nbandroid.org/2011/07/how-to-fix-broken-communication-with.html can help you. Also check if the IDE sees the device - go to Services tab (Ctrl-5) and expand Android devices node. You should see your emulator/connected device.

Next to the output from compilation is another tab with an output from the deployment. Check what is written there.

If you cannot manage to get it working consider filing a bug report. There are hints how to do it at http://www.nbandroid.org/p/contacts.html

-Radim